# Finding the infinite sum using Leibniz Test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, summation

I have been given a task in my previous lecture to determine whether the infinite sum;
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (\pi n)\ln n}{n}$$
Converges or diverges. 
My perspective on the problem is that we will have to use the Leibniz test as $$\forall n\in \mathbb[N],\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n $$
So I thought that because $\cos(\pi n)$ is always negative we can apply the Leibniz test. I don't, however, understand how we are meant to prove the conditions whereby $a_n\geq 0$ or $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly $(-1)^n$ is not always negative. Secondly, this just converges by the alternating series test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ by L’Hopital’s rule.

$$|a_n| \geq |a_{n+1}| \iff \frac{\operatorname{ln}n}{n} \geq \frac{\operatorname{ln}n+1}{n+1} \iff n^{n+1} \geq (n+1)^n $$

Which holds for all $n$ large enough.

Comment: One way to see the last statement is that it is equivalent (by dividing both sides by $n^n$) to $n \ge (1+\frac1n)^n$. The left hand side obviously tends to infinity, the right hand side tends to $e$.